# Windows 8.1 batch file - closing separate command window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I'm trying to run a batch file that will close a different cmd window. I know I can do this:

```
TASKKILL /IM "myapplication.exe" /F
```

But whilst this does (obviously) kill the task, it doesn't close the cmd window myapplication.exe was running in. I cannot edit myapplication.exe or I would put an 'exit' on the last line.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is your application started resulting in not closing command processor after started application terminated itself?

Comment: I'm using [McAfee's Rootkit Remover](http://www.mcafee.com/uk/downloads/free-tools/rootkitremover.aspx) tool which is not an install, its a run once type thing.

But, I want to run it every night so I'm running the exe via Windows Task Scheduler. However, the exe doesn't close itself after running. You have to press a key to get it to shut. So, what I did was create a batch file with the code above which is also scheduled to run, but 10 mins later when the exe will have finished scanning.

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question. How exactly is Rootkit Remover tool started? What is the command line used to start it? For example using `cmd /K "Path\application.exe"` starts the application, but because of `/K` the command window is kept open for user input after application terminated. Or is the application started with a batch file? What is the command line in the batch file? Depending on how the application is started, a specific title for the console window can be set making it possible to close that window from other application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your program was started from `cmd`, then obviously `cmd` is still running even if you kill or exit that application. To kill `cmd` as well you can apply the same command to a different program (in a quite obvious way).

However, this will also stop your batch file for equally obvious reasons.

Is there a particular need to run `myapplication` from `cmd`?